# set the right value to setCompressionQuality() when compressing the image

Tags: java

I am trying to compress an png image (6.8 MB) to reduce its size but I am facing the problem that I am loosing to much of its quilty. Even if I comment these line

```
        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        param.setCompressionQuality(0.9f);
```

I getting an image as in the screenshots but with size of (812 KB). With the lines I am getting an png image with size of (1.24 MB) but in the both cases I am getting the image as in the screenshots without different in the
quility (also with black background). How can compress the image with better quilty? Also I thought I could configure the quality vlaue by setting a float value between 0-1 as the following setCompressionQuality(0.9f);

```
package ImageCompressor;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;


public class ImageComprossor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {

            File input = new File("strawberry.png");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

            File compressedImageFile = new File("strawberry_compressed.png");
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

            Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
            ImageWriter writer = writers.next();

            ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
            writer.setOutput(ios);

            ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            // Check if canWriteCompressed is true
            if (param.canWriteCompressed()) {
                param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
                param.setCompressionQuality(0.9f);
            }
            // End of check
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `jpg` to get the `ImageWriter`? Because if you change to `ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png")` and then try to get the available compression types (i.e. `param.getCompressionTypes()`), you'll get a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Compression not supported`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set png in this method getImageWritersByFormatName("png"); then the image looks the same but with bigger size --> its size is 11.2MB.